# Rails Asset Pipeline and admin specific javascript and css

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

Newish to rails and I've read that I should put all my JS/CSS into `applications.js`/`applications.css` and have it handled by the asset pipeline. However, I have a decent amount of js/css that is only used when an admin is logged in and adding/editing pages.

It seems to me that it's a lot of overhead to load those scripts and styles on every page. What's the best way to go about optimizing this? I can create a separate asset pipeline that only gets included when admins are logged in, or only on pages where it's necessary?

**-EDIT 3-**
The below will work in production, however you need to add: `config.assets.precompile += ['editing.js', 'editing.css.scss']` to `production.rb`

**-EDIT 2-**
The below doesn't actually work on production. Looking for a better solution when I get a minute.

**-EDIT-**

This is the setup that I've come up with. It works properly, so I guess I'm asking if there is any reason that I shouldn't do it this way?

**application.html**

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %meta{:charset => "UTF-8"}
    %meta{name: "Description", content: "base10 CMS"}
    %title= "base10 CMS"

    = stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all"
    = javascript_include_tag "application"
    = csrf_meta_tags

    - if admin_signed_in?
      = stylesheet_link_tag "editing", media: "all"
      = javascript_include_tag "editing"
      = cloudinary_js_config

  %body
    #container
      #messages
        - flash.each do |name, msg|
          = content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}"
      #content
        = yield
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
```

**editing.js**

```
//= require ckeditor/init
//= require cloudinary
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/.
```

**application.css.scss**

```
/*
 *= require baseline
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require font-awesome
 *= require_self
*/

@import 'mixins.css.scss';
@import 'layout.css.scss';
@import 'pages.css.scss';
```

**editing.css.scss**

```
/*
 *= require_self
*/

@import 'mixins.css.scss';
@import 'admin.css.scss';
@import 'forms.css.scss';
```

Comment: You can create a new `admin_layout` with required css/js in app/views/layouts which will get applied to admin views see the layout for more http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts

Comment: this seems like a sensible way to go about it.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is fine. One thing to keep in mind is that in production, all the directives within the `application.js` and `application.css.scss` manifests will get **compiled** and **minified** into a single file (`application.js` and `application.css` respectively) so in most cases there won't be much overhead. If there is tons of extra stuff that you're including to support logged-in admins, then yes, your approach is fine, otherwise, I wouldn't worry about it and just leave everything in the `application.*` manifests.